# How to concatenate the values of two input fields where only second value is editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, selection-api

Please help me cause i'll like to have the value of the second input field, **id='bold'** to concatenate with the value of the **id='field'** on load like this **CAN'T TOUCH THIS!gaggle**.

**CAN'T TOUCH THIS!** is currently not editable using selectionStart
but i'll like **gaggle** to be editable.

**HTML**

```
<input id="field" type="text" value="CAN'T TOUCH THIS!" size="50"/>
<input id="bold"  type="hidden" value="gaggle" size="50"/>

<div id="output">
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('document').ready(function(){

var readOnlyLength = $('#field').val().length;
$('#output').text(readOnlyLength);

$('#field').on('keypress, keydown', function(event) {
    $('#output').text(this.selectionStart);

    if ((event.which != 37 && (event.which != 39)) && ((this.selectionStart < readOnlyLength) || ((this.selectionStart == readOnlyLength) && (event.which == 8)))) {
        return false;
         }
        });    

})
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Yt72H/999/.

Let me know if clarification is needed. Thanks.

Comment: Please include, **in the question itself**, a [mcve]. [We expect there to be code in the question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/), that's why it wouldn't let you post the question without code, and with just a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

On the load event of your page you can get initial value of 'giggle' input and 'don't touch this' input (those actual strings), concatenate them together into new variable (concat) and overwrite the value in 'don't touch this' with concatenated value that holds joined strings (concat variable). You will see that 'don't touch this' will stay readonly and 'giggle' part you can actually edit.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
     var concat = $('#field').val() + $('#bold').val();
     $('#field').val(concat);
     // rest of your code
});
```

Comment: Hi Mirko. i did similarly. Was just hoping gaggle would be editable. Maybe i'm asking for the impossible. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well 'giggle' field is hidden what exactly you want to achieve ? 
Do you want to update giggle field with value entered in 'Don't touch this' field ?

Comment: Can you provide an explanation with your answer?